# Composer binary built when installed

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer package can include [vendor binary](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md). If my repository has a file "bin/foobar.phar" in it, I can add this to my composer.json:

```json
{
    "name": "foobar/cli",
    "bin": ["bin/foobar.phar"]
}
```

Then when I install this "foobar/cli" package, the file "bin/foobar.phar" will be installed to "vendor/bin".

My question is how do I do this without commiting the "bin/foobar.phar" file to my repository? Let say I can build the file by running the script "composer build":

```json
{
    "name": "foobar/cli",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "@php build.php --target=./bin/foobar.phar"
    },
    "bin": ["bin/foobar.phar"]
}
```

How do I setup my repository so the bin target is built when installed by project depends on "foobar/cli"?

I've tried to put "@composer build" into the following [event hooks](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names), none seems to work:

- pre-install-cmd
- post-install-cmd
- pre-update-cmd
- post-update-cmd
- pre-package-install
- post-package-install
- pre-package-update
- post-package-update

Package like [phpunit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/main/composer.json) seems to have pulled this off. There should be a way for it.

Please suggest what I should try. Thanks.

Comment: "Package like phpunit seems to have pulled this off" - what do you mean by that? Their composer.json references a file called `phpunit`in the root folder, and that definitely exists

Comment: Why do you want the client to build the phar?

Comment: I want to prevent the distributed .phar from outdated. One way to do that is to setup git hook and build it before commit. I'm simply exploring if there is another way.

Comment: You could do it as other do it: build the PHAR to a different repository on tagging a new version

Comment: @NicoHaase: Right. I was blind... -_-